# how to enable developer mode for extension in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

this question is not the same as [How to prevent users to go in debug mode with their browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887053/how-to-prevent-users-to-go-in-debug-mode-with-their-browser)

everytime i open chrome, i would see the following remainder which tells me to disable that developer mode extension, this is anonying, how to disable this remainder?

[image]

Comment: Dude. You need to learn to search Stack Overflow before you ask. Please read through [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable developer mode extensions pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055651/disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop-up)

Comment: Use Linix or Mac instead of Windows, OR use Chrome from the Dev channel.